# Unable to compress file during Huffman Encoding in Java

Tags: java, encoding, huffman-code, compression

I have implemented the Huffman Encoding Algorithm in Java using Priority Queues where I traverse the Tree from Root to Leaf and get encoding example as #=000011 based on the number of times the symbol appears in the input. Everything is fine, the tree is being built fine, encoding is just as expected: But the output file I am getting is bigger size than the original file. I am currently appending '0' & '1' to a String on traversing left node and right node of the tree. Probably what I end up with uses all 8 bits for each characters and it does not help in compression. I am guessing there is some conversion of these bits into character values which is required. So that these characters use fewer bits than 8 and hence I get a compressed version of the original file. Could you please let me know how to achieve a compression by manipulating characters and reducing bits in Java? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a StringBuilder and appending "0" or "1", or simply the `+` operator to concatenate "0" or "1" to the end of your string.  Or you're using some sort of `OutputStream` and writing to it.

What you want to do is to write the actual bits.  I'd suggest making a whole byte first before writing.  A byte looks like this:

```
0x05
```

Which would represent the binary string `0000 0011`.

You can make these by making a `byte` type, adding and shifting:

```
public void writeToFile(String binaryString, OutputStream os){
    int pos = 0;
    while(pos < binaryString.length()){
        byte nextByte = 0x00;
        for(int i=0;i<8 && pos+i < binaryString.length(); i++){
            nextByte << 1;
            nextByte += binaryString.charAt(pos+i)=='0'?0x0:0x1;
        }
        os.write(nextByte);
        pos+=8;
    }
}
```

Of course, it's inefficient to write one byte at a time, and on top of that the OutputStream interface only accepts byte arrays (`byte[]`).  So you'd be better off storing the bytes in an array (or even easier, a `List`), then writing them at bigger chunks.

If you are not allowed to use byte writes (why the heck not? ObjectOutputStream supports writing byte arrays!), then you can use Base64 to encode your binary string.  But remember that Base64 inflates your data usage by 33%.

An easy way to convert a byte array to base64 is by using an existing encoder.  After adding the following import:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
```

You can instantiate the encoder and turn your byte array into a string:

```
byte[] bytes = getBytesFromHuffmanEncoding();
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
String encodedString = encoder.encode(bytes);
```

Comment: You are right, I am using a + operator to concatenate '0' or '1' to the end of the string. But I need to use a String "Str" to write output to the file in Ascii 32 bit format (instead of writing actual bits) as you suggested. Can I achieve this? Code is   ObjectOutputStream ObjOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(EncFile));
  ObjOutputStream.writeObject(Str);

Comment: Maybe I can convert every Byte I obtained into a char and store it in String Str?

Comment: @user997509 that's pretty much what Base64 does.  It maps binary to strings, but it's not optimal and can only encode 6 bits for every byte that it uses, inflating your resulting file.  But it's the best you can hope for if you are sticking with ASCII strings only.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation it is very helpful. I would like to clarify that I cannot use Byte Writes since I do not have access to the source code where the file is being written but I have access only to write to Str so It can be used to write to the output file. Are there any pointers on how to use Base64 to encode the Binary String? Thanks a lot

Comment: In your code, what is pos? It does not seem to be incrementing and the loop hangs... public void writeToFile(String binaryString, OutputStream os){
    int pos = 0;
    while(pos < binaryString.length()){
        byte nextByte = 0x00;
        for(int i=0;i<8 && pos+i < binaryString.length(); i++){
            nextByte << 1;
            nextByte += binaryString.charAt(pos+i)=='0'?0x0:0x1;
        }
        os.write(nextByte);
    }
}

Comment: @user997509 I fixed.  The whole thing would be a lot simpler to explain if you pretend you're processing 1 bit at a time, then it's a much smaller jump to understand that it's processing 8 bits at a time.