# java huffman compressor output bigger than original

Tags: java, huffman-code

I'm doing a Huffman compressor for homework and I managed to build the Huffman tree and the code of 0 and 1 for all the char but the output file is bigger then the original.
There was a question which like mine here
[Unable to compress file during Huffman Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801591/unable-to-compress-file-during-huffman-encoding-in-java)
but I didn't get it very much.
My code:

```
        this.HuffmanTreeBulid();////create the Huffman tree
        HuffmanNode root =tree; 
        this.codeGenerator(root, codes);//create the hushmap

        try 
        {
            FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);//for the new file
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileInput);//for reading again the orignal file
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter(fileOut);
            //String code;
            char currentchar;
            int currentByte;//int for going on all the bytes from the file
            if(!fileOut.exists())//if new file exits then replace it if not create it 
                fileOut.createNewFile();
            else
            {
                fileOut.delete();
                fileOut.createNewFile();
            }



            while((currentByte = in.read())!=-1)
            {
                int currentint =currentByte& 0xff;//"& 0xff" is for unsigned int 
                currentchar=(char)currentint;
                byte[] c=(huffmanCodes.get(currentchar)).getBytes();
                //out.write(huffmanCodes.get(code2));
                //out.write(huffmanCodes.get(currentchar));//for FileWriter
                out2.write(c);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            out2.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

updete 1:
i understand the problem so i traid doing this

```
         int bitIndex = 0;
            for (int i=0;i<codes.length();i++)
            {
                if(codes.charAt(i)=='1')
                    buffer.set(bitIndex++);
                else
                    buffer.clear(bitIndex++);
            }
```

still dosnt work :(

updete 2: im doing this for getting the byte from the string

```
             byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(binaryString, 2).toByteArray();
                for (byte b : bytes) 
                {
                    out2.write(b);
                }
```

still wont work but its the close i can get till now
maybe the byte is fine but im writing in a wrong way?

Comment: Do you realize that `0` and `1` are actual _bits,_ such that eight of them constitute a byte? You're representing them as characters, but I don't see where do you pack them into a bitstream and then cut that stream into bytes for writing into a file; maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: with updete 2 i did debug and i reley dont get what wrong, 
for char ! the string is 010010101111000
and bytes is [37, 120], 
which is good
so how come it didnt work? 
the original file was 329Kb
the output is 359Kb @Michriko

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is the following line:

```
 byte[] c=(huffmanCodes.get(currentchar)).getBytes();
```

You try to get your coded String to bare bits and bytes. But in fact, `getBytes()`returns just the encoded bytesequence in your platform standard. So you get maybe an UTF-8 Byte encoding for the character "1" and an UTF-8 Byte encoding for the character "0". 
You have to parse your String to a byte. You can see how to do so here: 
[java: convert binary string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883428/java-convert-binary-string-to-int)

or here: 
[How to convert binary string to a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959840/how-to-convert-binary-string-to-a-byte)

you can read more about the getBytes method here:
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-getbytes-method-example/

as @9000 mentioned you do not have a Bitstream.

Working with compressors bitstreams might be more suitable than working with complete bytes. so parsing a complete byte will not compress your string as a char remains the size of a char.

what you can do, is to concatenate the resulting binary strings and then parse the string to bytes at the end. Be aware of trailing zeros.

Comment: alrght i get ther problem so thnks for that but what i dont know is what the sulution
i already tried so many thing
like goinf on the string and creating a bitset 
if the char at the string is 1 then set
if else the clear
while adding intex 
and still wont work
@Michriko

Comment: without the code you tried i can't help. i'm not a clairvoyant ;D

Comment: i wanted to add the code but its get uglt in here..im new to  asking in stackoverflow.
int bitIndex = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<codes.length();i++)
    {
     if(codes.charAt(i)=='1')
      buffer.set(bitIndex++);
     else
      buffer.clear(bitIndex++);
    }

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding something like this:

```
class BitstreamPacker {
  private int bitPos;  // Actual values 0..7; where to add the next bit.
  private ArrayList<Byte> data;

  public addBit(bool bit) {
    // Add the bit to the last byte of data; allocate more if does not fit.
    // Adjusts bitPos as it goes.
  }

  public void writeBytes(ByteOutputStream output) {
    // Writes the number of bytes, then the last bit pos, then the bytes. 
  }
}
```

Similarly,

```
class BitstreamUnpacker {
  private byte[] data; // Or ArrayList if you wish.
  private int currentBytePos;
  private int currentBitPos;  // Could be enough to track the global bit position.
  public static BitstreamUnpacker fromByteStream(ByteInputStream input) {
    // A factory method; reads the stream and creates an instance.
    // Uses the byte count to allocate the right amount of bytes;
    // uses the bit count to limit the last byte to the actual number of bits.
    return ...;
  }

  public Bool getNextBit() {
    // Reads bits sequentially from the internal data.
    // Returns null when the end of data is reached.
    // Or feel free to implement an iterator / iterable.
  }
}
```

Note that the bit stream may end at the middle of the byte, so storing the count of bits in the last byte is required.

To help you better understand the idea, here's some Python code (because Python is easy to play with interactively):

```py
class BitstreamPacker(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []  # A list of bytes.
        self.bit_offset = 0  # 0..7.

    def add_bit(self, bit):
        if self.bit_offset == 0:  # We must begin a new byte.
            self.data.append(0)  # Append a new byte.
        # We use addition because we know that the bit we're affecting is 0.
        # [-1] means last element.
        self.data[-1] += (bit << self.bit_offset)
        self.bit_offset += 1
        if self.bit_offset > 7:  # We've exceeded one byte.
            self.bit_offset = 0  # Shift the offset to the beginning of a byte.

    def get_bytes(self):
        # Just returning the data instead of writing, to simplify interactive use.
        return (len(self.data), self.bit_offset, self.data)
```

How does it work from Python REPL?

```
>>> bp = BitstreamPacker()
>>> bp.add_bit(1)
>>> bp.add_bit(1)
>>> bp.get_bytes()
(1, 2, [3]) # One byte, two bits in it are used.
>>> bp.add_bit(0)
>>> bp.add_bit(0)
>>> bp.add_bit(0)
>>> bp.add_bit(1)
>>> bp.add_bit(1)
>>> bp.add_bit(1)
>>> bp.get_bytes()
(1, 0, [227])  # Whole 8 bits of one byte were used.
>>> bp.add_bit(1)
>>> bp.get_bytes()
(2, 1, [227, 1])  # Two bytes used: one full, and one bit in the next.
>>> assert 0b11100011 == 227  # The binary we sent matches.
>>> _
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help but can you explain further about the addBit?
i mean i have my binaryString so now i loop on it and check each char at i and if it 0 add(0) and if 1 then add(1)?
and i updated with something new but it still wont work can you check it please? @9000

Comment: @MBDarkstrike: I extended my answer; try playing with that code and understand how it works.